# Stop looping of text in else statement

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I've added an if statement inside my while loop to show specific data to a specific user, but I would like to add an ELSE statement of `echo"No Notifications";`. Only it prints this text out over and over for the amount of times I've asked the loop to print results out in the SQL query. How can I stop this so it just shows the else statement the once inside the `<div class="notif_ui">`div?

```
while($notificationchant=mysqli_fetch_assoc($chant)){

       if($_SESSION['id']==$notificationchant['notification_targetuser']){
            ?>
            <div class="notif_ui">
            <div class="notif_text">
    <div id="notif_actual_text-<? echo $notificationchant['notification_id'] ?>" class="notif_actual_text">
            <?
             echo "<img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped".$notificationchant['notification_triggeredby'].".jpg?photo_time=" . time()."\" onerror='this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><a href='".$notificationchant['notification_throughurl']."'>".$notificationchant['notification_content']." </a><br />";
            echo "".Agotime($notificationchant['notification_time']).""; 
            ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <? }}?>
```

Comment: i didn't get it clearly.. do you want to add and else statement then simply add it there after if !!

Comment: Yes I would like to add the else statement in.. which I know how to do obviously. But I don't know how to stop the else text from printing out the 6 times I've asked the while loop to perform for the if statement. I just want NO NOTIFICATIONS to print out once and not six times inside the while loop

Comment: @Dave You should check if the total count of notifications for said `$_SESSION['id']` and if it `= 0` then show the `echo "No notifications;"` otherwise you run the loop to echo out what notifications there are for said user. Alternatively you could modify the `sql` query to fetch the notifications for said user?

Comment: Cheers Darren, I have got it working now. Pano below posted exactly what I were looking for and it works like a charm. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable and set it to 0

```
$didEcho = 0;
```

Check if the variable is 0 in your else

```
else if ($didEcho == 0){
    echo 'No Notification';
    $didEcho = 1;    
}
```

Then in your else change it to 1

Comment: Fantastic, Just what I were looking for. Thanks Pano, works like a charm.